# Adding simple menu in python

Tags: python, shell

All, I wrote a small python script to parse out data from a log file. I was able to parse out what I need. Now I am trying to create a menu so that user can choose which data they want to parse out rather than all of the log content. I am having a little struggle trying to figure out how to do it, could someone please help me start on making a menu. I am a newbie to Python.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re

with open('temp.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group()    
    time = line.split()[3]
    ids = line.split()[4]

    try:
        agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        agent = 'agent:'
    try:
        errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        errID = 'ErrIdText:'
    try:
        clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
    except:
        clear = 'clearedID:'

    row = [date, time, ids, agent, errID, clear]
    data.append(row)

 for row in data:
 print(row)
```

So I want to make a menu so user can choose if they only want to parse out the date and the agent name for example.

Comment: Take a look at [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [click](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/) to implement your menu through the command line. It will parse the arguments and you will be able to filter out the operations. It is also easy to understand and implement for simple stuff. For example:

```
import re
import click

date_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}')
agent_pattern = re.compile(r'agent:\s(.*?),')
err_pattern = re.compile(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),')
clear_pattern = re.compile(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)')


@click.command()
@click.option('--filter-agent', is_flag=True, default=False, help='Filter agent')
@click.option('--filter-err-id', is_flag=True, default=False, help='Filter Error ID')
@click.option('--filter-cleared-id', is_flag=True, default=False, help='Filter Cleared ID')
@click.argument('filename')
def get_valid_rows(filter_agent, filter_err_id, filter_cleared_id, filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    data = []
    for line in lines:
        date = date_pattern.match(line).group()
        time = line.split()[3]
        ids = line.split()[4]
        row = [date, time, ids]

        if filter_agent:
            try:
                agent = agent_pattern.search(line).group()
            except:
                agent = 'agent:'

            row.append(agent)

        if filter_err_id:
            try:
                errID = err_pattern.search(line).group()
            except:
                errID = 'ErrIdText:'

            row.append(errID)

        if filter_cleared_id:
            try:
                clear = clear_pattern.search(line).group()
            except:
                clear = 'clearedID:'
            row.append(clear)

        data.append(row)

    # Do everything else


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_valid_rows()
```

It'll even generate a well-formatted help message for you

```
Usage: parselog.py [OPTIONS] FILENAME

Options:
  --filter-agent       Filter agent
  --filter-err-id      Filter Error ID
  --filter-cleared-id  Filter Cleared ID
  --help               Show this message and exit.
```

You could edit it to your liking to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: To confirm, this will work through command line argument. does not required any user interface? Because I want to have it as command line argument. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will work through the command line and does not require any user interface. To use it, run `python parselog.py --help` for the help menu.

Comment: I do not have click on my machine....is there another way to implement command line without using click?

Comment: You can install click via `pip install --user click` which will require having pip installed. Since you said you're a newbie, you should get acquainted with pip and installing packages with pip. Otherwise, the other option would be to use Python's own [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's a very large question, but what you need is either a UI (like [Tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) or [Pyqt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)) or a command line interface (which you could implement yourself, or build using a library like [docopt](http://docopt.org/)).

However, the command-line option will be a lot simpler to implement.